# How to make a request with querystring params using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an api method with a URL like this: http://api.website.com/app.php?action=SOMETHING&id=SOME_NUMBER

I the only part that changes on each request is the id querystring, replacing SOME_NUMBER (ex: http://api.website.com/app.php?action=SOMETHING&id=556).

I'm creating the service like this:

```
public interface MyService {
    @GET("acao=SOMETHING")
    Call<ComicBookResponse> get(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

And I use a factory class to return an instance of the service:

```
public static MyService myService() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.website.com/app.php?")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(MyService.class);
    }
```

However, the requests seem to be ignore the @Query parameter. What is wrong with this?

Comment: "However, the requests seem to be ignore the @Query parameter" -- how are you determining this? AFAIK, your syntax is fine. I have a few sample apps that use Retrofit for querying the Stack Exchange API. Here's the Retrofit interface file for one of them: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/HTTP/Retrofit/src/com/commonsware/android/retrofit/StackOverflowInterface.java

Comment: Try this
change your endpoint in your service to 

    `baseUrl("http://api.website.com/")`

And the method you use to 

    `@GET("app.php?acao=SOMETHING")
    Call<ComicBookResponse> get(@Query("id") String id);`

Comment: @CommonsWare you were right. The syntax was right, the error was a missing item in the URL. I'll close this question.

Comment: Moderators please close this question as the error was just a typo in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static MyService myService() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.website.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MyService.class);
}

public interface MyService {
    @GET("/app.php")
    Call<ComicBookResponse> get( @Query("action") String action, @Query("id") String id );
}
```

Now it will form url like :

```
http://api.website.com/app.php?action=SOMETHING&id=556 // if action=SOMETHING and id=556
```